# Simple, powerful visualization

Tags: graphics, data-visualization

I am looking for a tool/framework to do some simple, yet rather intensive visualization.

I have ~10000 points in a 2D space. All I need to do is plot these points, then have them animate from place to place on a second by second basis. Up until ~1000 points I was able to achieve this using Raphael.js in a web-browser, however I need a more powerful solution now.

Does anyone have any ideas where I should be looking for such a tool?

Preferred interface languages: Ruby, C, Java, Haskell or a REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give [Processing](http://processing.org/) a try. If you're familiar with Java and C the processing syntax should be comfortable. Alternatively there is a JavaScript version, [processing.js](http://processingjs.org) you could try.

Answer (score 0):

[TK](http://www.tkdocs.com/) -- typically used with [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm). A very simple cross platform GUI scripting language. I have been using it successfully for a variety of 2D UIs capable of displaying 10e6+ shapes on a canvas and have recently used it for [C++ heap map visualizer](http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/cpp-heapmap) GUI. Lots of cut/paste code fragments available on the [wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/). There are multiple ways to use it from within C++, including [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)-based binding.